# I Need to Tie Together My Paypal IPN Script with My Users Table

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, paypal

I've searched and researched the answer to my question on both Google.com and Stackoverflow.com this is my last resort. I have a website with an already functional paypal payment system and registration/login system. My problem is that I'm trying to tie the two together. I know that the ipn script receives information from paypal and inserts it into the paypal_register table under my database. The Registration/Login also has it's own table within the same database. The problem is that intuitively I thought I could just take the session/cookie information from the registration/login script and put it in the paypal table when the IPN runs. Theres a section in my paypal ipn where upon success and verification it enters all of the variable into the paypal table. When I tried to set the $username and $email to the one the user used to login it did not work. However I know why it didn't work and it's because the paypal IPN script functions separately and is called by paypal.com, right?

I just need to figure out how to update my registered user's status to paid after they've successfully paid the payment. The paypal IPN I have already works and the successful payments are put into the database. It's really just connecting the login with the paypal.

Comment: How I would normally approach such a problem would be to insert the session or cookie login information like Username and Email into the paypal table. That's how I'd like it to work, but since the paypal IPN is just called by paypal theres no way to get that session / cookie data over to the IPN where it submits the information.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there's some sort of transaction ID that you can send to Paypal with your payment request that appears in the IPN call for exactly this purpose. It's a while since I used Paypal, so I don't have the details.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I'd go about using the transaction ID to set a registered user to paid?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. See I was using an IPN script I purchased from codecanyon.com. In the end I just changed the variables around and inserted them into a MySQL database. Thanks for the help but the problem I stated was too specific.